# NSURL becomes null when passed as a parameter iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-management, methods, parameters, null

I have set up a couple of very simple methods that play with NSURLs and NSStrings.
the first method that gets called is getAudio. I want to set the variable audioPath equal to cleanAudio so that it can be used later in the encryptWithAudioFile. The problem is somewhere along the way when it is being passed as a parameter the object becomes null. I have no idea why and I have tried every method I can think of in terms of memory management to try and keep the object. The logs I have used work result as follows
NSLog(@"Clean Audio1: %@", audioPath); Perfect, works as it should 
 NSLog(@"Clean Audio2: %@", audioPath);
 NSLog(@"Clean Audio3: %@",    audioPath);
 NSLog(@"Clean Audio4: %@", audioPath);

```
@implementation Stub

@synthesize audioPath,
userText;

-(NSURL *)retrieveAudio:(NSURL *)cleanAudio{

self.audioPath = cleanAudio;
NSLog(@"Clean Audio1: %@", audioPath);

return cleanAudio;
}

-(NSString *)retrieveText:(NSString *)message{

self.userText = message;
NSLog(@"Text: %@", self.userText);
NSLog(@"Clean Audio2: %@", audioPath);

return message;
}

-(void)startEncrption{
NSLog(@"Clean Audio3: %@", self.audioPath);
[self encrypterWithAudioFile:self.audioPath withString:self.userText];
}


-(NSURL *)encrypterWithAudioFile:(NSURL *)audio withString:(NSString *)text{
NSLog(@"DIRTY AUDIO and TEXT: %@, %@", audio, text);

return audio;
}

-(void)dealloc{
[super dealloc];
[audioPath release];
[userText release];
}

@end
```

Edit: Here's the .h

```
@interface Stub : NSObject {

NSURL *audioPath;
NSString *userText;

}

-(NSURL *)retrieveAudio:(NSURL *)cleanAudio;
-(NSString *)retrieveText:(NSString *)message;
-(void)startEncrption;
-(NSURL *)encrypterWithAudioFile:(NSURL *)audio withString:(NSString *)text;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURL *audioPath;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *userText;
```

I'm calling the methods in other classes as follows:

```
stubObj = [[Stub alloc] init];
[stubObj retrieveAudio:recordedTmpFile];
```

and

```
stubObj2 = [[Stub alloc] init];
[stubObj2 retrieveText:textView.text];
[stubObj2 startEncrption];
```

Edit: I should probably have mentioned that I have three views, all with different controllers running on a UIScrollView that are calling the [Stub] interface.

Comment: By naming convention you should not use the word **get** in a method name, unless you are using an out arguments to return a value.

Comment: Style note: your use of "get" as in `getText:` is confusing, as `getText:` actually sets the `userText` property. "get" is normally reserved for getter methods that return a value in a reference parameter.

Comment: Are you using the iOS 5.0 beta SDK? And what does the code that calls these methods look like?

Comment: Tried changing the names of the methods but still the same problem persists. I am using iOS 4.3

Comment: I'm calling the methods like so: stubObj2 = [[Stub alloc] init];
        [stubObj2 retrieveText:textView.text];

Answer (score 0):

I would look into your memory management and make sure you are not over releasing that URL some where after you've passed it into this methods.  What I can see from your current code is that (assuming your audioPath property is marked `retain`) you are actually over retaining it within this snipped when you are assigning it:

```
self.audioPath = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"TEST"];
```

Should be:

```
self.audioPath = [NSURL urlWithString:@"TEST"];
```

Comment: I had initially tried that and it doesn't work. No matter what I declare in that method, even dummy variables, they turn up null when passed as an argument later.

Comment: I figured it out finally by storing my variables in my delegate. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are allocating the NSURL only in -[Stub getAudio:], right?  It also looks like you are creating multiple Stub objects.  Are you calling the getAudio: method on each of those objects before trying to use the audioPath property on that object?  That could be your problem.

Comment: Hmm, I am creating multiple Stub objects. However I am only calling get audio with the stubObj and getText with stubObj2. I should probably have mentioned that I have three views, all with different controllers running on a UIScrollView that are calling the [Stub] interface.

Answer (score 0):

In your latest update of the post, you include 2 different examples of how you use this class. In the first one you have this:

```
stubObj = [[Stub alloc] init];
[stubObj retrieveAudio:recordedTmpFile];
```

I assume that this is working, and that your "Clean Audio1:" log shows the expected URL, is that correct?

In your next example you have this:

```
stubObj2 = [[Stub alloc] init];
[stubObj2 retrieveText:textView.text];
[stubObj2 startEncrption];
```

Since this is a new instance and you never call retrieveAudio on this instance, the audioPath property for this instance is never set so it is nil. When you call startEncrption it calls encrypterWithAudioFile and passes self.audioPath, which is nil. Isn't this what you are expecting or am I missing something here?

Comment: I scraped this idea entirely and moved all my variables to my delegate. Check out my answer. Your input was much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a fix. I ended up moving all my variables to my app delegate and referenced them from other classes by pointing to the delegate::

```
RonnieD1AppDelegate *appDelegate = (RonnieD1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I removed the startEncryption method altogether and called the method encryptWithAudioFile like this:

```
    [stubObj2 encrypterWithAudioFile:appDelegate.audioPath withString:appDelegate.userText];
```

My final code ended up looking like this:

```
@implementation Stub

-(NSURL *)retrieveAudio:(NSURL *)cleanAudio{
    RonnieD1AppDelegate *appDelegate = (RonnieD1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication    sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.audioPath = cleanAudio;
    NSLog(@"Clean Audio (retrieveAudio): %@", appDelegate.audioPath);

    return cleanAudio;
}

-(NSString *)retrieveText:(NSString *)message{
   // self.audioPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"TEST"];
    RonnieD1AppDelegate *appDelegate = (RonnieD1AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.userText = message;
    NSLog(@"Text: %@", appDelegate.userText);
    NSLog(@"Clean Audio (retireveText): %@", appDelegate.audioPath);
    return message;
}

//-(void)startEncrption{
//    NSLog(@"Clean Audio (startEncryption): %@ TEXT: %@", self.audioPath, self.userText);
//    //self.audioPath = [NSURL URLWithString:@"TEST"];
//    [self encrypterWithAudioFile:self.audioPath withString:self.userText];
//    
//}


-(NSURL *)encrypterWithAudioFile:(NSURL *)audio withString:(NSString *)text{
NSLog(@"DIRTY AUDIO and TEXT: %@, %@", audio, text);

    return audio;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

I know there are still some memory management issues with this but its working finally so I can figured that out myself. Thanks for all your help.